# Function based on element visibility not working?

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I'm trying to run two different sets of functions, based on whether or not an element is visible when another element is clicked.  Here is the whole function:

```
$('#grid').click(function() {
  if('#photo_grid:hidden') {
    $('#grid').addClass('active').removeClass('fadein');
    $('.cycle-slideshow').fadeTo('fast',0.3);
    $('#photo_grid').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $('#grid').addClass('fadein').removeClass('active');
    $('#photo_grid').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.cycle-slideshow').fadeTo('slow',1.0);
  }
});
```

This results in the classes being added/removed from `#grid` and `.cycle-slideshow` being faded to 30% on the first click, as required.  `#photo_grid` does not fade in, however, and subsequent clicks fail as a result.  Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Page is live [here](http://new.element17.com), with the `#grid` button being the lower-rightmost one.

Comment: FYI, you're asserting a string.

Comment: Your `if` is *very* wrong, I'd suggest: `if ( $('#photo_grid:hidden').length)` *or* `if ($('#photo_grid').is(:hidden'))`

Comment: Not just the regular kind of wrong... Thanks!  The latter suggestion is what I went with.  Can you put this in an Answer so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `if` is that you're effectively testing for the presence of a string, whereas what you're *trying* to do is respond to the visibility of an element. Therefore I'd suggest either:

```
if ($('#photo_grid:hidden').length)
```

Or:

```
if ($('#photo_grid').is(':hidden'))
```

The `.length` check ensures that there is one, or more, items returned by the selector (as jQuery *always* returns an array (even if it's an *empty* array), whereas the `is()` method returns a Boolean to reflect the element is matched, or unmatched, by the selector passed to the method.

References:

- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad to have been of help! And, of course, thank you for the accept! =)